# How to mock a firestore DeltaDocumentSnapshot in firebase functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

According to this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/unit-testing), you can create a mock DeltaSnapshot for firebase realtime database. But I am trying to test a firebase function using firestore, and here the event has this type:

`event: firebase.Event<firebase.firestore.DeltaDocumentSnapshot>`

So how do you mock this event, so you can unit test functions utilizing firestore triggers?